Generate HMAC Signature for AWS S3 API call using Flutter
I am trying to perform the list-type 2 API call in order to list the contents of a bucket. Following the steps here, I am stuck at the calculating signature step.
Using their example parameters



Parameter
value




AWSAccessKeyId
AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE


AWSSecretAccessKey
wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY



Request timestamp of 20130524T000000Z (Fri, 24 May 2013 00:00:00 GMT).
Bucket name examplebucket.
The bucket is assumed to be in the US East (N. Virginia) Region. The credential Scope and the Signing Key calculations use us-east-1 as the Region specifier. For information about other Regions, see Regions and Endpoints in the AWS General Reference.
I am able to replicate their results through "StringToSign"
import 'package:cryptography/cryptography.dart' as c;
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

// can hopefully just paste the below into the _incrementCounter function of the boilerplate Flutter project
  void _incrementCounter() async {
    var accessKey = 'AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE';
    var secretKey = 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY';
    var date = '20130524T000000Z';
    var canonicalRequest = "GET\n";
    canonicalRequest += "/test.txt\n\n";
    canonicalRequest += "host:examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com\n";
    canonicalRequest += "range:bytes=0-9\n";
    canonicalRequest +=
        'x-amz-content-sha256:e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855\n';
    canonicalRequest += 'x-amz-date:$date\n\n';

    canonicalRequest += 'host;range;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date\n';
    canonicalRequest +=
        'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855';
    var stringToSign =
        "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n$date\n20130524/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request\n${sha256.convert(utf8.encode(canonicalRequest)).toString()}";


    var hmac = c.Hmac.sha256();

    var dateKey = await hmac.calculateMac(utf8.encode("20130524"),
        secretKey: c.SecretKey(utf8.encode(secretKey)));
    var regionKey = await hmac.calculateMac(utf8.encode("us-east-1"),
        secretKey: c.SecretKey(dateKey.bytes));
    var regionServiceKey = await hmac.calculateMac(utf8.encode("s3"),
        secretKey: c.SecretKey(regionKey.bytes));
    var signingKey = await hmac.calculateMac(utf8.encode("aws4_request"),
        secretKey: c.SecretKey(regionServiceKey.bytes));

    var signature = await hmac.calculateMac(utf8.encode(stringToSign),
        secretKey: c.SecretKey(signingKey.bytes));
    var signatureString = hex.encode(signature.bytes);
  }

My signature string ends up as 0803da67fcc3f3e9becec8f473692023d30e8c3b095de60b863fc2082f63d388, where their example is f0e8bdb87c964420e857bd35b5d6ed310bd44f0170aba48dd91039c6036bdb41
I also tried using the crypto package to calculate the HMAC:
    var  dateKey = getHmac256Digest(
        utf8.encode("AWS4$secretKey"), utf8.encode("20130524"));
    var dateRegionKey = getHmac256Digest(
        utf8.encode(dateKey.toString()), utf8.encode('us-east-1'));
    var dateRegionServiceKey = getHmac256Digest(
        utf8.encode(dateRegionKey.toString()), utf8.encode('s3'));
    var signingKey = getHmac256Digest(
        utf8.encode(dateRegionServiceKey.toString()),
        utf8.encode('aws4_request'));
    var signature = getHmac256Digest(utf8.encode(signingKey.toString()),
        utf8.encode(stringToSign)); // DateTime.now().toIso8601String();

  // declared below _incrementCounter
  Digest getHmac256Digest(List<int> encodingKey, List<int> hashValue) {
    return Hmac(sha256, encodingKey).convert(hashValue);
  }

This method results in f03131e53fcdcd3605054f5ead58370d14a672add94bda5da0a69d65d03e7edc, which looks closer but no cigar :(
Does anyone have any insights/previous experience calculating the authorization signature using Flutter? Thanks in advance.

A typo in the first code snippet: The signing key of the first HMAC is wrong: Correct is secretKey: c.SecretKey(utf8.encode("AWS4" + secretKey)). In the current code the prefix AWS4 is missing.

In the second code snippet, the signing keys are corrupted by the hex encoding via toString(), e.g. utf8.encode(dateKey.toString()). This must be replaced by dateKey.bytes. Likewise for dateRegionKey, dateRegionServiceKey and signingKey. The similarity of the HMACs is pure coincidence.

@Topaco doh.... I have too many screws loose, thank you for pointing that out! My signature actually matches if I add the "AWS4" prefix to my key, go figure. Now I just need to adapt my bucket, etc., and figure out the 403 error. Your first comment answers my question, if you posed it as an answer I can mark it confirmed.
